# polymerfire syncs empty key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer, polymerfire

Polymer syncs an empty dynamically generated id with the data then syncs the data with the data binded key. How do i stop this from happening.

```
<firebase-document
    path="/users/[[authenticatedUser.id]]/token"
    data="[[messagingAPI_TOKEN]]">
</firebase-document>
```

expected outcome:

```
{
   "users" : {
       "57f49f8ffaf7e800116e96e2" : {
          "token" : reallyLongToken
       }
    }
 }
```

actual outcome:

```
{
   "-KhitjHsZDTjsIezQBiZ" : reallyLongToken,
   "users" : {
       "57f49f8ffaf7e800116e96e2" : {
          "token" : reallyLongToken
       }
    }
 }
```

Looks like the "ghost" data is created as a result of null return from [[authenticatedUser.id]]. Because it is dynamic and not from my system is is wasteful and fills the database with unwanted data.

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/issues/33

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put your firebase-document element inside a `template dom-if` like below:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[authenticatedUser.id]]">
  <firebase-document
    path="/users/[[authenticatedUser.id]]/token"
    data="[[messagingAPI_TOKEN]]">
  </firebase-document>
</template>
```

Comment: Glad it worked, can you please accept the answer so that anyone else having the same problem can get benefited!